# remove a sub-string from a string in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two strings in VBA lets say,

```
Dim str1 as String
Dim str2 as String

str = "I.3) Haupttätigkeit(en)"
```

and

```
str2= "I.3)"
```

I want to remove str2 from str1.  Is it possible in VBA ?

This is what I am doing:

```
Dim strResult As String

' Position of str1
intPos = InStr(1, str1, str2)
If intPos > 0 Then
    ' str2 found,
    strResult = Left(str1, intPos - 1)
Else
    ' str2 not found, so take whole string
    strResult = str1
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is quite simple to do with `Replace function`:

```
str1 = Replace(str1, str2, "")   'result: Haupttätigkeit(en)
```

However, it will keep leading space after replacement, therefore you could try in this way (removing leading or ending spaces):

```
str1 = Trim(Replace(str1, str2, ""))   'result:Haupttätigkeit(en)
```

Alternatively you could use `Mid Statement` [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264462%28v=office.15%29.aspx).